# Create a New Table Oder by Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table in below format,

```
UserName        SessionID

A.MCGREGOR      SFNeBNnG7300               
AB17            SFkPeL9INTER               
AB17            SFqXMAyINTER               
AB17            SFWoXtgINTER               
ABruce          SFBTNvYBJ300               
Accounts        SF7ctc9F3700               
Accounts        SFjLXZwF3701
```

I need this information in another table group by UserName. I need UId generated based on the unique username as follows,

```
UId UserName        SessionID

1   A.MCGREGOR      SFNeBNnG7300               
2   AB17            SFkPeL9INTER               
2   AB17            SFqXMAyINTER               
2   AB17            SFWoXtgINTER               
3   ABruce          SFBTNvYBJ300               
4   Accounts        SF7ctc9F3700               
4   Accounts        SFjLXZwF3701
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: insert into newtable select Row_number() over(Partition by UserName order by UserName) as UID, UserName , SessionID from oldtable.

Comment: @DeepakPawar why don't you put you comment as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below solution :

```
INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT Dense_Rank()
         OVER(ORDER BY UserName) AS UID,
       UserName,
       SessionID
FROM   oldtable
```

or if you want the column in same table then :

```
ALTER TABLE oldtable
  ADD UID INT
GO

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Dense_Rank()
                  OVER(ORDER BY UserName) AS rn,
                UserName,
                SessionID
         FROM   oldtable)
UPDATE cte
SET    Uid = rn
```

Comment: Hi Deepak. Thanks for your help. Actually Row_Number() inserts dynamic row number for each row of the table. I have achieved it by using DENSE_RANK() as follows,

Comment: SELECT DENSE_RANK()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY UserName) AS rn,
                UserName,
                SessionID
         FROM   Test

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I just messed up with something and created this solution. updated answer with your suggestions.